# WSO2 ESB how to sending array list empty error

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I Configurate url like:

```
https://htygnfgvsccl.com:6753/intellige/vehicle/getAlerts
```

this url some times getting data like

```
{
"alertsList": [

                   {

                    "vehicleNo": "45342",

                    "alertName": "Stop Skipped",

                    "depotName": "akividu"
                   },
                    {

                    "vehicleNo": "674894",

                    "alertName": "Stop Skipped",

                    "depotName": "guntur"
                   }
                ]
            }
```

but some times getting data like

```
{
"alertsList": []
}
```

every time response code is 200 but how to send with error message in the case of  alertsList  empty

vehiclegetAlertsapi

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/intellige/vehicle/getAlerts" name="vehiclegetAlertsapi" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="GET">
        <inSequence>
            <property description="http" name="HTTP_SC" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="404"/>
            <log level="full"/>
            <send>
                <endpoint key="vehiclegetAlertsendpoint"/>
            </send>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <switch source="get-property('axis2','HTTP_SC')">
                <case regex="200">
                    <log description="200log" level="custom">
                        <property expression="$ctx:ERROR_CODE" name="200reserrorcode"/>
                    </log>
                    <send/>
                </case>
                <default>
                    <log description="reslog" level="custom">
                        <property expression="$ctx:ERROR_CODE" name="reserrorcode"/>
                        <property expression="$ctx:ERROR_MESSAGE" name="reserrormessage"/>
                        <property expression="get-property('axis2','HTTP_SC')" name="reshttpsc"/>
                    </log>
                </default>
            </switch>
            <clone continueParent="true">
                <target>
                    <sequence>
                        <sequence key="vehiclegetAlertsmail"/>
                    </sequence>
                </target>
            </clone>
            <send/>
        </outSequence>
        <faultSequence>
            <switch source="get-property('axis2','HTTP_SC')">
                <case regex="200">
                    <log description="200log" level="custom">
                        <property expression="$ctx:ERROR_CODE" name="200reserrorcode"/>
                    </log>
                </case>
                <default>
                    <log description="reslog" level="custom">
                        <property expression="$ctx:ERROR_CODE" name="reserrorcode"/>
                        <property expression="$ctx:ERROR_MESSAGE" name="reserrormessage"/>
                        <property expression="get-property('axis2','HTTP_SC')" name="reshttpsc"/>
                    </log>
                </default>
            </switch>
            <clone continueParent="true">
                <target>
                    <sequence>
                        <sequence key="vehiclegetAlertsmail"/>
                    </sequence>
                </target>
            </clone>
            <send/>
        </faultSequence>
    </resource>
</api>
```

vehiclegetAlertsendpoint

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<endpoint name="vehiclegetAlertsendpoint" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <http method="get" uri-template="https://htygnfgvsccl.com:6753/intellige/vehicle/getAlerts "/>
</endpoint>
```

vehiclegetAlertsmail:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="vehiclegetAlertsmail" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <log level="custom">
        <property name="status" value=" vehileget alert Details Sending mail"/>
    </log>
    <property expression="get-property('axis2','HTTP_SC')" name="ErrorMessage" scope="default" type="STRING" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
    <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/json"/>
    <property name="ContentType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="text/plain"/>
    <property name="Subject" scope="transport" type="STRING" value="vehileget alert api not working"/>
    <property name="OUT_ONLY" scope="default" type="STRING" value="true"/>
    <property name="FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="true"/>
    <payloadFactory media-type="json">
        <format>{"vehileget alert api not working":"$1"}</format>
        <args>
            <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:ErrorMessage" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
        </args>
    </payloadFactory>
    <call>
        <endpoint key="vehiclegetAlertsmailid"/>
    </call>
    <drop/>
</sequence>
```

vehiclegetAlertsmailid:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<endpoint name="vehiclegetAlertsmailid" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <recipientlist>
        <endpoint>
            <address uri="mailto:aisha@gmail.com"/>
        </endpoint>
    </recipientlist>
</endpoint>
```

get 200 response code send the data automatically in case if any other reponse to send the mail my mail id ,prsent my problem is my rest url some time total data like alertsList with data  comming some times only alertsList comming not comming data that case how to send mail

Comment: Hi Aisha, welcome to SO. Can you show us your code for the API? Do you want the e ESB to send an error message after it receives  an empty array from the DSS?  Assuming it is indeed the DSS getting the data and the ESB calling the DSS service and processing the response.

Comment: Hi  @ophychius update my code please find and i hope please solve my problem @ ophychius